# react-hook-form stops working when put into a .map() - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

Probably being stupid here but I'm struggling to get this working. I'm trying to create a form based off an object. Everything is fine when I'm not using a loop, but when I do, it stops working.

**Checkbox.tsx**

```
const Checkbox = React.forwardRef(
    ({ label, name, value, onChange, defaultChecked, ...rest }:any, forwardedRef:any) => {
      const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(defaultChecked);
  
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if (onChange) {
          onChange(checked);
        }
        console.log(checked, 'checked')
        console.log(name, 'name')
      }, [checked]);
  
      return (
        <div onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          <input
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            ref={forwardedRef}
            type="checkbox"
            name={name}
            value={value}
            checked={checked}
            onChange={e => {
              setChecked(e.target.checked);
            }}
          />
          [{checked ? "X" : " "}]{label}
        </div>
      );
    }
  );
```

My Test() parent component:

```
export default function Test() {
  const onSubmit = (data:any) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Checkbox
          ref={register({ required: "This is required" })}
          name="styles"
          value={"tops"}
          label=" tops"
        />
        <Checkbox
          ref={register({ required: "This is required" })}
          name="styles"
          value={"bottoms"}
          label="bottoms"
        />
        {errors.styles && <p className="error">{errors.styles.message}</p>}
        <h2>Next section</h2>
        <Checkbox
          ref={register({ required: "Please select a colour" })}
          name="colors"
          value={"red"}
          label=" Color (custom checkbox)"
        />
        <Checkbox
          ref={register({ required: "Please select a colour" })}
          name="colors"
          value={"blue"}
          label=" Color (custom checkbox)"
        />
        {errors.colors && <p className="error">{errors.colors.message}</p>}
        <button type="submit">submit</button> 
      </form>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Everything works properly here, my data is structured as follows on submit:

```
{"styles":["bottoms","tops"],"colors":["blue"]}
```

My problem arises when I try to build out the form from an object, like so:

**'../content/formStyle'**

```
const girl = [
    {
        name: 'styles',
        checkboxes: [
                {
                    value: 'dresses',
                    label: 'Dresses',
                },
                {
                    value: 'pants',
                    label: 'Pants',
                },
                {
                    value: 'skirts',
                    label: 'Skirts',
                },
                {
                    value: 'shorts',
                    label: 'Shorts',
                }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'colors',
        checkboxes: [
            {
                value: 'coral',
                label: 'Coral'
            },
            {
                value: 'lime',
                label: 'Lime'
            },
            {
                value: 'mint',
                label: 'Mint'
            },
            {
                value: 'raspberry',
                label: 'Raspberry'
            },
            {
                value: 'red',
                label: 'Red'
            },
            {
                value: 'purple',
                label: 'Purple',
            },
            {
                value: 'teal',
                label: 'Teal'
            },
            {
                value: 'blue',
                label: 'Blue'
            },
            {
                value: 'pink',
                label: 'Pink'
            }
        ]
    }
]

export { girl }
```

And the component changes to:

```
import {girl} from '../content/formStyle'

export default function Test() {
  const onSubmit = (data:any) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {girl?.map((section, index:any) =>{
        return (
          <>
            <h2 className="font-bold">{section.name}</h2>
            {section.checkboxes.map(checkbox => {
              return (
                <Checkbox
                  ref={register({ required: "This is required" })}
                  name={checkbox.value}
                  value={checkbox.value}
                  label={checkbox.label}
                />
              )
            })}
          </>
        )
      })}
        <button type="submit">submit</button> 
      </form>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I get the error:

```
react-hook-form.es.js?5302:429 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')
    at validateField (react-hook-form.es.js?5302:429:43)
    at eval (react-hook-form.es.js?5302:1199:1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the register part of `<Checkbox />` fixed it:

```
              <Checkbox
                key={index}
                ref={register()}
                name={checkbox.value}
                value={true}
                label={checkbox.label}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like `react-hook-form` makes things much harder whereas you could write your own implementation of `FormData`. I'm not able to explain why your code is not working, however I can propose an alternative explained easily here:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

function App() {
    const form = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null)

    const submit = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(form.current!);
        const name = data.get("name");
        console.log("name =", name);
    }

    return (
        <form ref={form} onSubmit={submit}>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="name" />
                <span>TRUC</span>
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Just like `react-hook-form` the goal here is to avoid countless states controlling the inputs. The FormData object will collect the values and create an object according to the names.

Note that `'on'` is used as value for a checkbox, not a boolean.

> **NOTE**: printing `data` in the console will show an empty object but the values are here.